# Java: print csv on different columns?

Tags: java, sql, csv, multiple-columns

I want to print the query table results on a CSV file.

I tried using this code:

```
PrintWriter csvWriter = new PrintWriter(new File(path + "SqlClient_" + date + ".csv")) ;
ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData() ; 
int numberOfColumns = meta.getColumnCount() ; 
String dataHeaders = "\"" + meta.getColumnName(1) + "\"" ; 
for (int i = 2 ; i < numberOfColumns + 1 ; i ++ ) { 
       dataHeaders += ",\"" + meta.getColumnName(i) + "\"" ;
    }
    csvWriter.println(dataHeaders) ;
    while (rs.next()) {
        String row = "\"" + rs.getString(1) + "\""  ; 
        for (int i = 2 ; i < numberOfColumns + 1 ; i ++ ) {
             row += ",\"" + rs.getString(i) + "\"" ;
        }
        csvWriter.println(row) ;
    }
    csvWriter.close();
```

This is what i obtain:

```
title1","title2","title3"
"date1","date2","date3"
....
```

This is write inside a single column, instead i want to write on different column, something like:

```
title1 | title2 | title3 
data1| data2 | data3 |
```

There is a special command to split the string into different columns?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the columns separated by the character `|` instead of `","`?

Comment: Ehm no xD xD The character | means that i's a different column.

Comment: So if I understand you, your csv file will look like: Title1 (one column), Title 2(another column), etc?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use a StringBuilder for this. Lets say you obtain a result set with a list of type YourClass from database call. Call the following utility and pass writer to it.

Pseudo code:

```
public void writeToCSV(FileWriter writer){

StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
for (YourClass data: yourresultSet){

sb.append("\"");
sb.append(data.getColumn1);
sb.append"\"";
sb.append(",\"")
sb.append(data.getColumn2);
sb.append("\"");
sb.append('\n'); //new line after the column

writer.write(sb.toString());
sb.delete(0,sb.length());

}

}
```

And to test your result

```
public class ReadCSV{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String csvFile = "your.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] title= line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            System.out.println("Columns [Column1= " + title[0] + " , Column2=" + title[1] + "]");

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSV files use a delimiter in order to separate the columns, so I'm guessing that your delimiter will be `,` (comma).

What you should do is print the value of the headers separated by comma and then append a new line separator (`\n`) in order to create a new column. And the same with the row values.

See this [example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/writeread-csv-files-in-java-example/) for further information about that.